# how to change upstream on Github

Tags: git, github

I have 3 forks of the same project as 3 remotes in my local git.

- Mainline - The Repo that was first created. Contains 278 commits after forking.
- Upstream - Initial fork of Mainline. Freezed in time. [Last commit March 12, 2014]
- DownStream - Forked from Mainline. Contains 150 commits after UpStream.

I am working on the repo Downstream. The Team maintaining Mainline refused to accept my PR. Hence I want to send a PR to Upstream and be able to send PRs to Upstream.

Just cann't seem to figure out how to do it on Github.

NOOB on git. So please point to answer if already answered although I have gone through most similar answers; the reason why this is here is - *I don't want changes on my local git repo alone. I want it on github too.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a GitHub Pull Request you can either use the GUI app or from the browser. Unfortunately there still is no way to send a Pull Request via the CLI.

Take a look at GitHub's Pull Request page for all of the possible ways to send a PR.
https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

Most importantly when sending a PR upstream make sure you pull down any upstream changes and resolve any potential conflicts first.

git remote add upstream git://github.com/user/repo.git
git pull upstream master

Comment: This link specifically helped https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests#changing-the-branch-range-and-destination-repository